# Efficient way of modifying just one value of a Series in Deedle (F#)

Tags: f#, series, deedle

Series are immutable in Deedle.

If i have a `Series<'K,'V>` and i have a function which returns a (new) Series which has only one different value for some (k,v) pair, how can i do that efficiently ?

if i do something like

```
Series.map (fun k v -> if (k=k0) && (v=v0) then myfun (k v)
                                           else v)
```

it would scan all keys ? I don't see any native function to do that in the library, is there any ?

or maybe i should consider another data structure ?

PS suppose keys are sorted also. (dates or numbers)

Comment: I think this is probably the way to do it - however, modifying one element is not something you'd often do in idiomatic Deedle code - what is the reason why you want to modify a single value?

Comment: I'm running an algorithm sequentially in a time series. I need to construct new series with values for each date.

conceptually its a fold on a data frame

Comment: Could you give some minimal concrete example? (Does not have to be your actual algorithm - anything that illustrates the access pattern will do!)